# CSS: Doubleclick for Publishers DIV breaks my DIV

Tags: css, google-dfp

I have the following DIV:

```
.mydiv {
    height: 255px;
    width: 620px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Inside that DIV I have AdSense code for a 300x250 ad, plus I also want to add DFP code for another 300x250 unit to the right of my AdSense unit.

When I put the DFP div inside mine - the DFP ad displays below the AdSense ad, instead of displaying to the right of it:

```
<div class="mydiv">

AdSense CODE

<div id="....." style="width:300px; height:250px;">
<script type="text/javascript">
DFP AD
</script>
</div>

</div>
```

I'm not that good with CSS, but I tried various position attributes for the DFP div (relative, absolute, etc.) yet it never worked the way I want it to.

Any ideas, what could be the problem and possibly the solution?

Thanks!

Comment: `float:left;` and that's about it.

Comment: Thank you! That worked exactly as I wanted to! You are my hero!